# What does "commercial suicide" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm an English Learner.

In "Communicating in Business English" (written by Bob dignen), there is a sentence: "Marketing this product would be commercial suicide" on page 52.

The dictionary says "suicide" means "destruction of one's own interests or prospects: financial suicide."

But I can't understand what "suicide" means. Would someone explain this?

Any help would be appropriated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Suicide" is used primarly to refer to "the action of killing oneself intentionally," in the context of human life, of course. In the sentence you've read, "commercial suicide" means just what that dictionary gave you: A damage to the commercial prospects or interests of a company or a firm that is so big, it is like destroying it, "killing" the company.